# OpenVPN does not start with the error Already running (PID file exists)

Tags: 11.10, openvpn

If I try to start OpenVPN, I get this error:

```
/etc/init.d/openvpn start
* Starting virtual private network daemon(s)...
* Autostarting VPN 'server'
* Already running (PID file exists)
```

But OpenVPN is not running, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read the error message? A Process ID file already exists. Usually this indicated that OpenVPN is already running. When you **cleanly** shut openVPN down it will remove this file.

If the laptop crashed, OpenVPN crashed or for some other reason this file did not get deleted then you can manually do that.

(In Other words: Make sure that OpenVPN really is not running, then remove the PID file You should find it in `/var/run/openvpn/`)

Comment: It was `/var/run/openvpn.server.pid ` actually, it worked :)